# Where are the logs for pfSense's dynamic DNS client?

Tags: pfsense

In the pfSense web interface, under Services -> Dynamic DNS -> Dynamic DNS Clients -> Edit, there is a checkbox labeled "Enable verbose logging", which the [pfSense docs](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/services/dyndns/client.html) claims to "increase the logging for the Dynamic DNS update process"; however I can't find a tab for Dynamic DNS logs under Status -> System Logs, and the Services -> Dynamic DNS doesn't offer a button for "Related log entries" like other services do. Furthermore there doesn't seem to be a log file for Dynamic DNS under `/var/logs`.

What gives? Where can I access the logs for pfSense's dynamic DNS client?

Answer (score 1):

I found them under Status -> System Logs -> System -> General (/status_logs.php). It's the default page for me when choosing Status -> System Logs from the menu. There isn't a separate Dynamic DNS log; the messages are mixed in with other system stuff.